# Python subclass method decoration

Tags: python

Is this code Pythonic?

```
def emit_decorator(method, signal_name):
    def decorated(self, *args, **kwargs):
        retval = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        getattr(self, signal_name).emit()
        return retval
    return decorated

class Model(base.Transformer, Node):
    """
    Transformer subclass that implements the Model of the Model-View-Controller
    paradigm.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    modelChanged = pyqtSignal()

    def create_view(self, parent=None):
        return View(self, parent)

for x in ('importance_changed',
          'evidence_changed',
          ):
    setattr(Model, x,
            emit_decorator(getattr(Model, x), 'modelChanged'))
```

---

Final decorator code:

```
from functools import update_wrapper

def method_emit_decorator(signal_name):
    def method_decorator(method):
        def decorated(self, *args, **kwargs):
            retval = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
            getattr(self, signal_name).emit()
            return retval
        return update_wrapper(decorated, method)
    return method_decorator

def class_emit_decorator(signal_name_to_method_names_dict):
    def class_decorator(cls):
        retval = cls
        for signal_name, method_names in (
            signal_name_to_method_names_dict.items()):
            for method_name in method_names:
                method = method_emit_decorator(signal_name)(
                    getattr(cls, method_name))
                setattr(retval, method_name, method)
        return retval
    return class_decorator
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the class after defining it smells. That is, its not necessarily a bad idea but one should explore options before resorting to it.

When "decorating" a function you should use the functools.wraps decorator. It will make the decorated function look more like the original.

The code you are replacing looks like:

```
def importance_changed(self):
    return_value = super(Model, self).importance_changed()
    self.modelChanged.emit()
    return return_value
```

Your code is harder to read and longer then just writing those two functions. Its not really worth implementing what you've done just for two functions. However, if you have a lot of functions then the situation changes.

Your emit_decorator function isn't a decorator. Dectorators have to take exactly one argument, (the function they are wrapping) to be used with the @syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the great tips!  I already have four such functions, so I thought this would be an easy way to save on boilerplate.  I don't know of any way of doing this without modifying the class after defining it.  Do you?

Comment: @Neil G, I do, but they are uglier then what you are doing. I might think about defining a class dectorator that connects all _changed() function to a modelChanged() signal.

Comment: I was just thinking along the same lines.  Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: I have taken all of your suggestions into account and produced two decorators.